# Htaccess move domains to subfolders

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to add a few rules to my .htaccess to achieve the following:

- `domain.com/(*.)` => `domain.nl/en/$1`
- `domain.de/(*.)`  => `domain.nl/de/$1`
- `domain.nl` stays `domain.nl`

I've been searching for quite a bit now and haven't found any solutions that help me properly. Surely this should be easy enough..

Currently got:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.nl/en/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.de [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.nl/de/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

The site is a Wordpress site that also has plenty of other rewrite rules, so I'm sure rewrite rules work. I've also placed these rules at the top of the file and the `[L]` directive should force it to skip any further lines..?

Finally got it to work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.nl/en/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.de [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.nl/de/$1 [R=301,L]


</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it this way.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.nl/en/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.de [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.nl/de/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks! But this gives me a 500 error.. I don't see an error in your code though

Comment: Sorry about that. Typo's. Try it again.

Comment: Still not working for me. Updated my question above. I'm testing by opening an incognito window every time, so that should clear any browser cache.

Comment: Nope, sorry, just not redirecting.

Comment: Do you have these domains on the same server with the vhosts configured properly to point there?

Comment: They are aliases of the main domain, so they all point to the same `www` folder.

Comment: Hold-up :-) Just noticed the `^`. The domain could however also have `www.` in front of it. More likely than not.

Comment: weird. Is DNS setup correctly? does domain.com point to your main domain IP? I know the rules work though. What OS is this?

Comment: is the domain www.domain.com?

Comment: No, I have updated my question. The `^` in the regex was ignoring the `www.` that is was using. However the site can be used both with or without `www.`

Comment: Thanks! My regex is a little rusty ;'-(

Comment: :) no problem glad you got it.